# Change the focus on jQueryUI Datepicker on close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want jQueryUI to change the focus to another element after the picker is closed:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        $("#time").focus();              //doesn't work
    $("#time").addClass('debug');    //works
}
});
```

The above *should* work but unfortunately datepicker seems to have a command `inst.input.focus();` (I think) called *after* the onClose callback which resets the focus to the original input element. I'm wondering if there is way round this with bind().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have some delay and execute it if the plugin is setting the focus after `onClose` callback.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
      setTimeout(function(){
        $("#time").focus();
      }, 200);
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfecto! I was thinking of doing some delay but didn't realize it was so easy.